# Implementing `Promise.all()`

Tags: javascript, beginner, ecmascript-6, asynchronous, promise

I took a stab at implementing `Promise.all()`:

```js
"use strict";

function all (...promises) {
   const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let counter = 0;
      const values = [];
      let rejected = false;
      promises.forEach(
         (promise, idx) => {
            promise.then(val => {
                  counter++;
                  values[idx] = val;
                  if (counter === promises.length)
                     resolve(values);
               },
               () => {
                  if (!rejected) {
                     reject(new Error(`${promise} was rejected!`));
                     rejected = true;
                  }
               }
            );
         }
      );
   });
   return promise;
};
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What made you write this? How will it be used?

Comment: I was learning about promises. It would probably not be used since it's a reimplementation of something that already exists as a built in.

Comment: Whoa whoa hold your horses why is resolve suddenly called fulfill?

Comment: I guess I'll change that. I'm still learning promises, and the answer would be that I don't understand why it's called `resolve()` and not `fulfill()` in the first place.

Comment: When someone suggests a change to the *code* in a comment, don't edit your question, just note it, and maybe make a change to your actual code

Answer (score 4):

Good job using `const` for `values`, as well as `let` for re-assignable values like `counter` and `rejected`.

Did you test this code? My presumption is that it didn't happen, because when [I tried running it](https://jsbin.com/zumeculobe/edit?js,console,output), I see the following error:

> error promise.then is not a function

This is because the promises are spread out:

> ```
> function all (...promises) {
> ```

Without the spread operator it appears to run as I would expect, as long as each entry in `promises` is a promise.

I must admit I compared with [another implementation of `Promise.all()`](https://medium.com/@muralikv/implementing-promise-all-in-javascript-732076497946). In comparison with that function, yours tracks `rejected`, whereas the other one simply calls `reject` whenever a promise is rejected.

Another thing I noticed is that the variable name `promise` is reused - both for the outer promise to be returned by `all()` as well as the callback to `promises.forEach()`. It would be wise to use different names to improve readability. In fact there is little need to assign the outer promise - it can simply be returned without being assigned to a variable since it isn't modified after being instantiated.

Another aspect to consider is that [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) can accept promises or non-promises - e.g. the MDN documentation gives an example like this:

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42; // <- not really a promise
const promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
}).catch(error => {
   console.log('error: ', error.message); 
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

With your code, it throws the error `promise.then is not a function` so it might be wise to check if each item is a promise before calling `.then()` on it.

Comment: I did test the function, we probably just used it differently. It's been a while, but IIRC I went with spread because it was how I used the function.