# Implementation of Promise.race

Tags: javascript, beginner, asynchronous, promise

I took a stab at implementing `Promise.race()`:

```js
"use strict";

function race (...promises) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let [resolved, rejected] = [false, false];
      promises.forEach(promise => {
         promise.then(value => {
            if (!resolved) {
               resolve(value);
               resolved = true;
            }
         }, 
         reason => {
            if (!rejected) {
               reject(reason);
               rejected = true;
            }
         })
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: Given the issue I described when I tried to run your code for `Promise.all()` in [my answer for that post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/237116/120114), please [edit] your post to include sample inputs and expected/actual output- perhaps with a runnable snippet...

Comment: I’m voting to close this as *not working* because in [this sample bin](https://jsbin.com/jidarod/edit?js,output) that uses the code above there is an error in the console `TypeError: promise.then is not a function`